# jQuery Cycle Plugin: scrollHorz with Prev/Next - automatically scroll without user interaction?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, cycle

Using the jQuery cycle plugin: jquery.cycle.all.min.js - latest version (2.8.8) from http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/

I'm utilizing the scrollHorz effect with prev and next links. Works beautifully except for one thing, when the page loads, the slideshow isn't automatically scrolling, it requires the user to click prev/next.

Is there a way to make the slideshow automatically scroll on page load and continue to progress at a timed interval even if there's no user input? Basically, the way cycle works with its other more basic effects like 'fade'. I assume I'm missing an argument for cycle/scrollHorz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, it does it automatically. I had forgotten I had set 'timeout: 0' which disables auto-advance. Ahhh Friday after sake at lunch.